# Alloy related query

Tags: javascript, titanium-alloy

I am facing a issue while running one project.

```
[INFO] :   TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity resume. activity = com.aruman.test.t1.TestActivity@b50197b0
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [203,203] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,204] - In alloy.js:1,69
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [11,215] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Collections' of undefined
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,216] - Source: , module, __filename, __dirname, Titanium, Ti, global, kroll) {Alloy.Collectio
[INFO] :   Choreographer: Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at alloy.js:1: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Collections' of undefined
```

can anyone help me on same.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It says your collection, which appears to be on line 1 of your alloy.js file isn't defined.  Post some code.  This may not appear to be the actual line in your code file.  It appears it is the first actual line of NON-comments that has a problem.

Comment: Have removed all comment lines still it gives same error. Done clean of project as well